# Difference of two subharmonic functions and signed measures

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-functions, geometric-measure-theory

One of the reasons subharmonic functions are interesting is that if you take their laplacian, you get a measure (and conversely any finite Radon measure with compact support can be obtained in this way).

Observation : if you take the laplacian of the difference between two subharmonic functions, you should get a signed measure. For example, I know that any smooth function is the difference of two smooth subharmonic functions. Taking the laplacian, you get a signed measure with density with respect to Lebesgues.

Question : is there a bit of theory available in this direction (e.g. are differences of 2 subharmonic functions interesting as functions), that would be similar to the classical theory of subharmonic functions and Radon measures ? Or is there nothing to be said that doesn't just follow from the usual theory ?

Comment: I think if $\mu$ is a Radon measure with compact support, you can use the fundamental solution for $\Delta$ to obtain a function $f$ with $\Delta f = \mu$.  Splitting $\mu$ into positive and negative parts $\mu_+$ and $\mu_-$, and solving $\Delta f_\pm = \mu_\pm$, we get $f = f_+ + f_-$ where $f_+$ and $-f_-$ are subharmonic.  I think playing around with this might show that functions $f$ such that $\Delta f$ is a Radon measure (with enough decay at infinity) are differences of subharmonic functions.

Comment: @user835747 well probably. I realize my question is a bit vague ; I was mostly asking for a reference. To be more specific though, I am interested in the kind of convergence needed for a sequence of functions that are the difference of two subharmonic functions to converge to a function whose laplacian is a signed measure (I'm not asking that the limit of laplacians converge to the laplacian of the limit).

Comment: I guess an equivalent question is : how do you describe those functions $u$ such that $\Delta u$ is a signed measure ? (other than that they are differences of 2 sh functions). there is no mean inequality, but there should be some remaining structure

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/864287/147263) and comments there.