# The range of the distributional laplacean, defined in $W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$.

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded, smooth domain. Assume that $u\in W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$ and consider the distributional laplacean of $u$; $\Delta u$.

My question is: when is $\Delta u\in \mathcal{M} (\Omega)$?

If $\mu\in \mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ then, there is a unique $u\in W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$ such that $-\Delta u=\mu$ in the distributional sense, so my question is equivalently to know if $$\mathcal{M}(\Omega)\subset\Delta(W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)),$$

is a strictly inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Delta u$ is a signed measure, it can be decomposed into a positive and negative parts. Consequently, $u$ can be be written as a difference of two subharmonic functions. Such $u$ is called *$\delta$-subharmonic*.

There are $W^{1,1}$ functions that are not $\delta$-subharmonic. I'll give an example in one dimension: $u(x)=\int_0^x W(t)\,dt$ where $W$ is  the Weierstrass function (continuous, nowhere differentiable). You can arrange for zero boundary values by subtracting a linear function. Clearly, $u\in C^1\subset W^{1,1}$. On the other hand, the second distributional derivative of $u$ is the first distributional derivative of $W$, which is an unimaginable horror. The set of unimaginable horrors is disjoint from the set of signed measures.

In one dimension, $u''$ is a signed measure iff $u'\in BV$. In higher dimensions, the condition $\nabla u\in BV$ is sufficient, but not necessary for $\Delta u$ to be a measure. The necessary and sufficient condition is for $\nabla  u$  to be a *divergence-measure field*. (Look it up).

Comment: Thank you again. I was just to edit my post, because I have discovred that if $\Delta u\in \mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ then, $u\in W_0^{1,q}(\Omega)$ for all $q\in < N/(N-1)$, so any function $u\in W_0^{1,1}(\Omega)$, which does not belong to $W_0^{1,q}(\Omega)$ for some $q$ in that range, will do the job. Now there is just on thing confusing me. Is $\Delta u$ always a measure (unbounded measure), or it can be a worse distribution?

Comment: @Tomás It can be worse. You can still use $u$ from my post, which is $C^1$, and for which $u''$ is a horrible distribution.  In higher dimensions, just make it depend on one variable only and multiply by smooth cutoff to have zero on the boundary. In terms of Sobolev spaces, $u\in W^{2,1}$ is  (trivially) enough for $\Delta u$ to be a measure. For a more precise condition, see the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Do you know any reference which treats these thing systematically?

Comment: @Tomás Not in the signed case. There are good books on potential theory (Hayman-Kennedy, Armitage-Gardiner), but they deal with subharmonic functions, hence positive measures. The literature on $\delta$-subharmonic functions exists in the form of papers only. (Same for $\delta$-convex functions, which are differences of two convex functions). It's just hard to say enough coherent things about them to make a book.